# Reactjs - How to unit test login form in Vitest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, vitest

I am working on `React App` with `Vite` and `Vitest` for unit testing.

I Need to test the following cases on the **Login Form**

- Required validation on input. `// working fine
- Invalid username, and password (response coming form API). `// working fine
- Login Success. `// Not working as expected

On login success, it is **navigating** to `Profile Page`. When it comes to Unit test case it seems like it is not navigating properly. Here is what i Have tried so.

> React: `v18`, Vite: `4.4.4`, Vitest: `0.33`

Using [dummyjson](https://dummyjson.com/docs/auth) api for testing purpose

> Test file : `__tests__/Login/Validation.test.jsx`

```js
import { describe, test } from 'vitest';
import { fireEvent, render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import LoginPage from '../../src/pages/proteced-pages/LoginPage';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Store from '../../src/redux/store.js';
import { BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

const renderLoginPage = () => {
    render(
        <Provider store={Store()}>
            <BrowserRouter>
               <LoginPage />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
};

describe('Test ==> Login Form:', () => {

    // TEST 1
    test('Client side validation (REQUIRED): ', async () => {
        renderLoginPage();

        const submitButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /login/i });

        fireEvent.click(submitButton);

        await waitFor(() => {
            const emailError = screen.getByText('username is required.', { selector: 'span' });
            const passError = screen.getByText('Password is required.', { selector: 'span' });

            expect(emailError).toBeInTheDocument();
            expect(passError).toBeInTheDocument();
        });
    });

    // TEST 2
    test('Invalid username, password: ', async () => {
        renderLoginPage();

        const emailInput = screen.getByLabelText('username:');
        const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText('Password:');
        const submitButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /login/i });

        fireEvent.change(emailInput, { target: { value: 'Sam12_#' } });
        fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: 'pass' } });
        fireEvent.click(submitButton);

        await waitFor(() => {
            const invalidMessage = screen.getByText('Invalid credentials', { selector: 'strong' });
            expect(invalidMessage).toBeInTheDocument();
        });
    });

    // TEST 3 Not working
    test('Valid username, password: ', async () => {
        renderLoginPage();
        screen.debug();

        const emailInput = screen.getByLabelText('username:');
        const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText('Password:');
        const submitButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /login/i });

        fireEvent.change(emailInput, { target: { value: 'kminchelle' } });
        fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: '0lelplR' } });
        fireEvent.click(submitButton);

        expect(emailInput.value).toBe('kminchelle');
        expect(passwordInput.value).toBe('0lelplR');

        await waitFor(() => {
            const profilePageHeading = screen.getByText('Profile pages', { selector: 'p' });
            console.log(profilePageHeading)
            expect(profilePageHeading).toBeInTheDocument();
        });
    });
});
```

**Error message**

> Unable to find an element with the text: Profile pages, which matches selector 'p'. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

Comment: you are searching for Profile pages - not Profile page, maybe that the reason it doesnt find it?

Comment: I am looking to search for `Profile pages` which is html element (`<p>`) in Profile page. @codingStarter, On `screen.debug()` it is displaying login form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem replacing `BrowserRouter` with `MemoryRouter`

> *If someone has better suggestion then he is welcome to share.*

**Here is the solution that worked for me**

```js
//import profile page

import ProfilePage from '../../src/pages/auth-pages/ProfilePage';
```

```js
//replacing BrowserRouter with MemoryRouter

const renderLoginPage = () => {
    render(
        <Provider store={Store()}>
            <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/login']}>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
                    <Route path="/profile" element={<ProfilePage />} />
                </Routes>
            </MemoryRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
};

describe('Test ==> Login Form:', () => {

    // TEST 3
    test('Valid username, password: ', async () => {
        renderLoginPage();
        const emailInput = screen.getByLabelText('username:');
        const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText('Password:');
        const submitButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /login/i });

        fireEvent.change(emailInput, { target: { value: 'kminchelle' } });
        fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: '0lelplR' } });
        fireEvent.click(submitButton);

        expect(emailInput.value).toBe('kminchelle');
        expect(passwordInput.value).toBe('0lelplR');

        await waitFor(() => {
            const profilePageHeading = screen.getByText('Profile pages', { selector: 'p' });
            expect(profilePageHeading).toBeInTheDocument();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`getByText` is synchronous, i.e. it doesn't "wait" for the element to appear. Use `findByText` (`await findByText(//...`) instead.

Comment: i tried, but not working

Comment: @mbojo i have find the solution. would you like to add something?